# Saving a formatted textbox of type Date in Chrome & Firefox

Tags: c#, asp.net

I a got a Date field "Birthdate" in my web application. In aspx, I've set the field format as "dd/MM/yyyy".

```
<asp:TextBox CssClass="mytextbox"  runat="server" ID="DateTextBox1" Text='<%# Bind("DateOfBirth","{0:dd/MM/yyyy}") %>' TextMode="Date"></asp:TextBox>
```

In my code behind when inserting a record I save the Date text into a datetime variable:

```
person.DateOfBirth = DateTime.ParseExact(e.Values["DateOfBirth"].ToString(), "dd/MM/yyyy", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

In **Firefox** this is displayed as: [image]

While debugging the actual value is : 
[image]

In **Chrome** this is displayed as: [image]

While debugging the actual value is: [image]

My problem:

The difference in the date format for `e.Values["DateOfBirth].ToString()` causes my line of code to set "`person.DateOfBirth`" to crash, since for chrome the expected date is not in "`dd/MM/yyyy`" format.

I don't mind having different display formats but i need the actual value in the code to be one in order to convert it to datetime successfully.

Comment: What do you mean by _Firefox and Chrome displays_ exactly? If `e.Values["DateOfBirth"].ToString()` is `2016-02-01` in debugger, how do you think you can parse this string with `dd/MM/yyyy` format?

Comment: I mean when viewing the page in Firefox or Chrome

Comment: @SonerGönül I know I can't, that's why i'm asking my question, I need to unify the value in codebehind.